# Is ScrollIntoView synchronized in virtualstackpannel (Especially in WPF DataGrid)?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, itemscontrol, setfocus, itemcontainergenerator

We have a problem for focus a cell of DataGrid after Its data of bounded collection  has Refreshed.
for example we set a filter for its collection and then we want to refocus a stored cell of stored column.

Is it true that we think a call to ScrollIntoView is synchronized it means after call it our desired row and cell are created and we can set focus? (again it means after we call to ScrollIntoView , Is it true we think that Itemsgenerator finished its work and we can surly find our desired cell)

$

```
   //set filter of DataGrid Collection
DataGrid_Standard.ScrollIntoView(rowNumber,cellNumber);
//we sure our desired cell are created now
    DataGridRow row =           (DataGridRow)DataGrid_Standard.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    if (row == null)
    {
        // may be virtualized, bring into view and try again
        DataGrid_Standard.ScrollIntoView(DataGrid_Standard.Items[index]);
        row = (DataGridRow)DataGrid_Standard.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    }


        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

        // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);

            // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
            DataGrid_Standard.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, DataGrid_Standard.Columns[column]);
            cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);             cell.focus();
```

[Related](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/933b65b4-00ca-4fdd-8b15-615b8cc7c4ac/#b6a7c082-8b8a-494c-ae71-cacc7dae8188)

Comment: Any idea would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here's a datagrid Selection changed event handler that moves a virtualized row into view and then sets the focus to that row. This works for me:

```
        private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
        if (dg.SelectedItem == null) return;
        dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.SelectedItem);

        DataGridRow dg_row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dg.SelectedItem);
        if (dg_row == null) return;
       dg_row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));

    }
```

EDIT: Using the dg_row.MoveFocus method had an undesriable effect (a checkbox column required two clicks to set instead of one) and it worked better for me to just use

```
dg_row.Focus();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer But the big question is : sometimes "
DataGridRow dg_row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dg.SelectedItem);
        if (dg_row == null) return; " happens, we tried differnt situation unfortunately, It seems  above code in 99% of times but sometimes retrieved row or cell are null!!!!! It seems that they are not exactly sync and we have not heard about what is happening exactly between wpf main thread and wpf designer thread

Answer (score 0):

```
Action action = () =>
      {
        dg .ScrollIntoView(dg .SelectedItem);

        var item = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as DataGridRow;
        if (item == null) return;

        item.Focus();
      };

      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, action);
```

This should work fine for your case.